# Resetting Java's Authenticator

Tags: java, security, authentication

I'm using the [`Autheticator`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Authenticator.html) class to access a password-protected URL. I've extended it and created my own authenticator, and I set it as the default authenticator using [`Authenticator#setDefault(java.net.Authenticator)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Authenticator.html#setDefault%28java.net.Authenticator%29). Once I'm done accessing the URL, I'd like to reset the authenticator. The Javadoc says that setting it to null removes any previously set authenticator. But I'm not sure if that means that it has been reset to use the default authenticator (is there such a thing?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[In the source code of Sun's JDK implemenentation](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/6.0-JDK-Core/net/java/net/Authenticator.java.htm) *null is the default value*.